# Comparing SSD benchmarks

Tags: ssd, benchmarking, vertex-3

**here's the problem...**

I am looking at some SSDs benchmarks, but when comparing I didn't understand some benchmarks on tom's hardware and on passmark.
Why is the Vertex 4 behind the other two drives but has more iops and w/r speed?

[Su passmark (HDD benchmarks)](http://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/high_end_drives.html):

```
SSD OCZ Vertex 4 128GB 2.5"      2,666
SSD Corsair Force GT 120GB 2.5"  2,869
SSD OCZ Vertex 3 120GB 2.5"      2,798
```

IOPS

```
SSD OCZ Vertex 4 128GB 2.5"      R4kW 85000  M 120000
SSD Corsair Force GT 120GB 2.5"  R4kW     ?  M  85000
SSD OCZ Vertex 3 120GB 2.5"      R4kW 60000  M  85000
```

Can somebody explain how those differences come up?

Comment: Shopping advice is Off Topic on Super User. [Why it is so.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: I edited your question to make it readable and removed all the parts that made it look like a shopping rec. Feel free to revert the changes or edit it again.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english and wrong format of the question. Next time i'll do better

Comment: No problem, take a look at the FAQ and learn from reading other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Passmark are not very open about what kind of transfers give the most points, I'm unable to tell you why the Corsair Force GT scores higher than the Vertex 4. What I can tell you, is that there's multiple ways to measure drives' performance:

1. Sequentiel Read/Write (how quickly a drive can read/write a huge file, in sequence)
2. IOPS - Input/output per second. How quickly a drive can transfer multiple files. Changes dramatically by size, which is why you test for 512b, 1k, 2k, 4k, 8k etc. R/W. For OS-style operation of the ordinary user, 4k reads matter the most. [Source.](http://thessdreview.com/ssd-guides/beginners-guide/the-ssd-manufacturers-bluff/)

And suites like Passmark, which assign a certain value to each performance measurement, adding them together to give a "score" for each drive. Unfortunately these scores can be misleading, as what Passmark value as important, does not necessarily fit your usage scenario.

While not a perfect answer to your question, it might be the beginning of an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the explanation. Now i'll try to catch up what are the differences between the three SSD maybe with some close review of every piece of hardware. Greetings